# FormData append JSON

Tags: json, multipartform-data, form-data

How can I create the following result using FormData

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryOmz20xyMCkE27rN7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data";
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "description": "description"
}
------WebKitFormBoundaryOmz20xyMCkE27rN7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


FILE_DATA
------WebKitFormBoundaryOmz20xyMCkE27rN7
```

I am using

```js
const formData = new FormData();
const data = new Blob([JSON.stringify({
        description: 'description',
      })], {
        type: 'application/json'
      });
formData.set('data', data);
formData.set('file', file);
```

it generate

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryOmz20xyMCkE27rN7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "description": "description"
}
------WebKitFormBoundaryOmz20xyMCkE27rN7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


FILE_DATA
------WebKitFormBoundaryOmz20xyMCkE27rN7
```

As you can see we have a `filename="blob"` in JSON part , I want to remove it

I want to have a `data` field in my multipart data not a `data` file

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you do

```js
new Blob([JSON.stringify({
    description: 'description',
})], {
    type: 'application/json'
})
```

What you are really generating **is** a file, an UTF-8 text file, whose content will be `{description:'description'}` encoded in UTF-8.

So when you append it to your FormData, it is passed as a file, with the one particularity that you did set its Content-Type to `application/json`.

If you wish to send this data as part of the form-data's data in plain-text, that your server will be able to parse from the post-data directly, then just append your string as a key of your FormData:

```js
const data = JSON.stringify({
  description: 'description',
})
const fd = new FormData();
// append directly as part of the postData in plain text
fd.append('data', data);

console.log(...fd); // [key, value]
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another option which made it works for me

```
const dto_object = new Blob([JSON.stringify({
    description: 'description',
})], {
 type: 'application/json'
})
```

Then

```
formData.append("my_dto", dto_object, ""); // empty file name doesn't make it dissapear but it seems most server accepts it
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try add vars in PHP style and you have a good chance that your backend parse it correctly, as in my case.

Like:

```
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('name', 'Name');
  form.append('details[age]', '12');
```

In my case I did this

```
  const courseDto = {
      course_title: 'Title',
      course_category: 'My category'
  }

  const myForm = new FormData();
  courseForm.append("imageFile", this.file);

  Object.entries(courseDto).map(([key, value]) =>
    myForm.append(`course[${key}]`, value)
  );
```

And I got such result on backend in request.body:

```
course: {
   course_title: 'Title',
   course_category: 'My category'
}
```

And

```
imageFile on request.File
```